# How to get list of all keys defined in the routing e.g path, defaults, options etc and how can we add new custom key?

Tags: routes, 8

```
route_with_two_nodes:
  path: '/foo/{node1}/{node2}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\example\Controller\ExampleController::foo'
  options:
    parameters:
      node1:
        type: entity:node
      node2:
        type: entity:node
```

I need to get list of all keys path, defaults, options etc, where is it defined in Drupal Core ? so that if I need to add custom key and extend it

Comment: Are you looking for a documentation of routes in Drupal? https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/structure-of-routes

Comment: You mean you don't want to read the documentation and find this in the code? So start with the Symfony Routing component `Symfony\Component\Routing` and then look at the Drupal specific stuff in `Drupal\Core\Routing`

Comment: I need to know where is it defined in Drupal and suppose I need to add my own custom key where can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Add a route enhancer:

Example how `_form` gets replaced by `_controller`:

*Drupal\Core\Routing\Enhancer\FormRouteEnhancer:*

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\Core\Routing\Enhancer;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\EnhancerInterface;
use Symfony\Cmf\Component\Routing\RouteObjectInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;

/**
 * Enhancer to add a wrapping controller for _form routes.
 */
class FormRouteEnhancer implements EnhancerInterface {

  /**
   * Returns whether the enhancer runs on the current route.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Routing\Enhancer\Route $route
   *   The current route.
   *
   * @return bool
   */
  protected function applies(Route $route) {
    return $route->hasDefault('_form') && !$route->hasDefault('_controller');
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function enhance(array $defaults, Request $request) {
    $route = $defaults[RouteObjectInterface::ROUTE_OBJECT];
    if (!$this->applies($route)) {
      return $defaults;
    }

    $defaults['_controller'] = 'controller.form:getContentResult';
    return $defaults;
  }

}
```

Comment: so does this replace the _form key with _controller ?

Comment: Yes, this is a virtual `_form` key, which is in reality a `_controller` key pointing to a service providing a controller.

Comment: so _form would be present in routing.yml but in the backend it will always use _controller and list for which can be found from the Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation; which has private variables defined as $path, $name, $requirements, etc so if I need to add more private variables, I would have to extend this `Class Route` and add more variables which will be used further, is that correct?

Comment: The code above works on its own, it adds simply a _controller key for another key which otherwise wouldn't be recognized. You could do the same with your custom key. This is only an example, there are many other ways to extend routing. BTW annotation based route discovery is not used by Drupal, only YAML based.

Comment: can you provide YAML based discovery which is used by Drupal ? I could only find this Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation ?

Comment: This is a very Drupal specific thing, scanning module directories for YAML files, never looked into it, But it should be transparent for all keys you add, there is probably no processing at all happening in this part.